# Answering reviews on google play with service account

Tags: api, google-api, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

I wanna answer my application's reviews with service account. But regarding to api documantation of google play console, for answering review's, i need to have my auth'key. :

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/your_package_name/reviews?
access_token=your_auth_token
```

But in my json file that i got from "create key" on my service account page, i have nothing like: "auth token". What should i do?

Note: I also have 1 more small question: I wanna list all of my applications for google play. I found some non-offical api's that can retrieve all app's for spesific developer. But for that i need to have people's developer name that i cannot retrieve from any api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in my json file that i got from "create key" on my service account page, i have nothing like: "auth token". What should i do?

Your auth token is not in the key file you downloaded it contains what you need to request an access token.

Assuming that you have created service account credentials on Google cloud console.  What you have in that file is the credentials you need to create an access token.

> Your application calls Google APIs on behalf of the service account, so users aren't directly involved. This scenario is sometimes called "two-legged OAuth," or "2LO." (The related term "three-legged OAuth" refers to scenarios in which your application calls Google APIs on behalf of end users, and in which user consent is sometimes required.)

Requesting an access token using a service account requires a number of steps [Preparing to make an authorized API call](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests)  I recommend you look for a client library in your chosen language coding it yourself is not for the feint at heart.

> I wanna list all of my applications for google play.

In order to do that you will need to grant the service account access to your accounts data probably by sharing the data with it.   Or you will need to use Oauth2 to authorize your application then you will have access to it.